# how to separate code from html in java appengine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jsp, view

I'm learning how to make a google appengine app in Java now, and in their getting started guide, they use JSP's, but this seems to put a step back to my old days when I didn't know anything about MVC or separation of concerns.

I don't want to put code inside a template, and would rather use something similar to the django templates or jinja, the way you do in the python sdk. What's the best framework to do this?

I'm following the guestbook eexample in the getting started guide, where they tell you to make a JSP like this:

```
<html>
   <body>

<%
    UserService userService = UserServiceFactory.getUserService();
    User user = userService.getCurrentUser();
    if (user != null) {
%>
<p>Hello, <%= user.getNickname() %>! (You can
<a href="<%= userService.createLogoutURL(request.getRequestURI()) %>">sign out</a>.)</p>
<%
    } else {
%>
<p>Hello!
<a href="<%= userService.createLoginURL(request.getRequestURI()) %>">Sign in</a>
to include your name with greetings you post.</p>
<%
    }
%>

  </body>
</html>
```

but all those `<%` and `%>`s remind me of including PHP code in HTML pages, which is not the way I want to do this. Is there a way so I could create a view object, passing it some values, which will insert those into a template?

Comment: Depends what you're doing with your jsps.  You could have the JSPs handle REST calls and use a javascript library to handle the view based on the data returned.

Comment: At this point, I'm just following the guestbook example, which outputs the user's name inside the HTML.

Comment: There's a [django example](http://code.google.com/p/google-app-engine-samples/source/browse/trunk/django_example/), but I'm not sure it's as sophisticated as you'd hope.

Comment: This isn't really specific to App Engine - the same question applies to any Java servlet platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Google App Engine Wiki](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/WillItPlayInJava), JSP +JSTL is supported so there's no need of Scriptlets at all.

If you want a clean MVC architecture, maybe you should use a Framework that supports the pattern. The wiki says that **Struts** it's supported and also **Spring MVC**, so you can choose the one that suits your needs.

Answer (score 1):

There are some good frameworks that achieve what you want:

- [Tapestry](http://tapestry.apache.org/)
- [Wicket](http://wicket.apache.org/)

As [Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10197741/how-to-separate-code-from-html-in-java-appengine#comment13093181_10197741) said, I'll probably use a good js framework like [Backbone](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/) and REST

Answer (score 0):

grails work well for this....but it can be a bit of a pain getting everything setup correctly with the app engine framework

Answer (score 0):

My lightweight template engine, [Chunk Templates](http://www.x5software.com/chunk), will run in Google App Engine.

Chunk features includes, branching, looping, and macros, has a simple `{$tag}` syntax, and purposely does not allow inline java like jsp does (ick).  It's similar to twig/jinja/django/etc.

Plenty of built-in [tag filters](http://www.x5software.com/chunk/wiki/Chunk_Tag_Filters) too, eg:

```
{% $value|sprintf(%.02f) %}
{% $value|trim %}
{% $value|onempty("N/A") %}
```

The examples/recipes WAR is deployed in App Engine here: http://chunk-docs.appspot.com/